# How to port /{controller}/{action}/{id} routes in Pylons to Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, porting, pylons

So I'm porting some old Py2/Pylons app, which has the routes defined as in https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/pylons/examples.html section #3 which isn't possible in Pyramid - so how to deal?

I'm not familiar with neither Pylons nor Pyramid really, so if its obvious I'd still like a hint.

I have 8 controllers with ~2-5 actions each, where only some uses the {id}, I'm thinking I would need to decorate each action function in each controller with separate route_names, except for the ones which do not use any id:

```
@view_defaults(renderer='go.pt', route_name='go')
class GoView:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(match_param="action=list")
    def list(self):
        return {'name': 'Go list'}

    @view_config(route_name='go_edit')
    def edit(self):
        return {'name': 'Go edit id: {}'.format(self.request.matchdict["id"])}

    config.add_route("go", "/go/{action}"). # deals with all non-id routes pr controller
    config.add_route("go_edit", "/go/edit/{id}") # one for each controller+action using id
```

However, this gets to be quite many routes I need to add, compared to Pylons code - is this kosher Pyramid style, or is there some better way? Is it in fact better to add specific routes for each action whether it uses ID or not, even though it generates more calls to config.add_route?

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, your second route would never match. You would need to swap their order. See https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-declaration-ordering for explanation. As far as how and where to configure routes, take a look at the [SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch wiki tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html) and other [tutorials](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/index.html#tutorials).

Comment: Thats odd, the 2nd url does seem to work actually using /go/edit/123 I do reach the edit method. I looked at the example, however I don't see any silver bullets in there if I were supposed to - and thanks for your help BTW..

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Slashes are important, per https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-pattern-syntax. Anyway, regarding route configuration, it is preferred to separate configuration from classes and put them in one place because trying to debug matching routes can be tricky when they are scattered around your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyramid on its own requires granular route definitions. You can write helpers for this like

```
def add_action_routes(config, name, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = name
    if not path.endswith('/'):
        path += '/'
    config.add_route(name, path)
    config.add_route(name + '_action', path + '{action}')
    config.add_route(name + '_id', path + '{action}/{id}')

add_action_routes(config, 'go')
```

You can then use the `view_defaults` and `view_config` as you see fit to hook up views to these routes. On the flip side you could make your own url generator which deals correctly with generating a url of the correct format.

```
def make_action_url(request, name, action=None, id=None, **kw):
    if action is None:
        return request.route_url(name, **kw)
    if id is None:
        return request.route_url(name + '_action', action=action, **kw)
    return request.route_url(name + '_id', action=action, id=id, **kw)

config.add_request_method(make_action_url, 'action_url')
```

This will allow your code to use `request.action_url(...)` to generate urls without bothering too much with the route names.